# jQuery toggle not working and disappear elements

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

When I add this on my sites, all div disappear. What could happen?
What is wrong with the jquery code?

Jquery:

```
$( ".espacio" ).toggle(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("on").addClass("off");
});
```

CSS:

```
.off {height:200px}
.on {height:400px}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **[.toggle() event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)** is deprecated as of version `1.8` and removed in version `1.9`, you can use **[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** with **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** instead:

```
$(".espacio").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on off');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery UI you can use switchclass and add easing, animations. Something like

```
 $( ".espacio" ).click(function() {
    $(this)switchClass("off", "on", 1000, "easeInOutQuad");
     }, 
 function() {
   $(this).switchClass("on", "off", 1000, "easeInOutQuad");
});
```

Check out jquery UI .switchClass [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/).

Answer (score 1):

we can also use jQuery on function

```
$(".espacio").on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('off on');
});
```